# Show that if $X\in L^2 (\mathbb{P})$ then so is its conditional expectation.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have the following definitions: Let  $G_n$ partition the probability space, $\mathcal{G}$ be the sigma algebra generated by these sets,
$$
Y = \mathbb{E} [X \mid \mathcal{G}]= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[X \mid G_n] \mathbf{1}_{G_n},
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X \mid G_n\right]= \begin{cases}\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X 1_{G_n}\right]}{\mathrm{P}\left[G_n\right]} & \text { for } \mathbb{P}\left[G_n\right]>0 . \\ 0 & \text { for } \mathbb{P}\left[G_n\right]=0 .\end{cases}
$$

I would like to show the following

> If $X \in  L^{2} (\mathbb{P} )$ then $Y = \mathbb{E} \left[X  \mid  \mathcal{G} \right] \in  L^{2} (\mathbb{P} )$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable

I have tried to do this
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} |Y|^2 \, d\mathbb{P} &= \int_{\Omega} \left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[X \mid G_n] \mathbf{1}_{G_n} \right|^2 \, d\mathbb{P} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{\Omega} |\mathbb{E}[X \mid G_n] \mathbf{1}_{G_n}|^2 \, d\mathbb{P} \\
&= \sum_{n: \mathbb{P}(G_n) > 0} \int_{\Omega} |\mathbb{E}[X \mid G_n]|^2 \mathbf{1}_{G_n} \, d\mathbb{P} \quad \text{(Since we only consider non-empty sets)} \\
&= \sum_{n: \mathbb{P}(G_n) > 0} \frac{|\mathbb{E}[X \cdot \mathbf{1}_{G_n}]|^2}{\mathbb{P}(G_n)} \quad \text{(By the definition of conditional expectation)} \\
&\leq \sum_{n: \mathbb{P}(G_n) > 0} \frac{(\mathbb{E}[X \cdot \mathbf{1}_{G_n}])^2}{\mathbb{P}(G_n)} \quad \text{(By Jensen's inequality)} \\
&= \sum_{n: \mathbb{P}(G_n) > 0} \frac{\mathbb{E}[(X \cdot \mathbf{1}_{G_n})^2]}{\mathbb{P}(G_n)} \quad \text{(Since } \mathbb{E}[X] \text{ is a constant)} \\
&= \sum_{n: \mathbb{P}(G_n) > 0} \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^2 \cdot \mathbf{1}_{G_n}]}{\mathbb{P}(G_n)} \quad \text{(By the properties of squaring)} \\
&= \sum_{n: \mathbb{P}(G_n) > 0} \mathbb{E}[X^2 \mid G_n] \quad \text{(By the definition of conditional expectation)}
\end{align*}

**Question:** How do I proceed?

Comment: Hi, I have added the definition to the post. Measurability I think follows from the fact that it is the pointwise limit of measurable functions. However, integrability is what I am struggling with.

Comment: @geetha290krm thank you for the feedback. I have changed the formatting. On to the content, do we just apply jensen's inqualty to the sum on the first line and then apply it again to the expectation? I am n

Comment: You haven't defined $\mathcal{G}$. What is this, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $G_n$?

Comment: @FShrike yes, apologies.